# Heroku not allowing creating/reading from process

Tags: java, heroku, processbuilder

I was working on a project involving reading from another process when I noticed that it kept throwing `java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found`, so I made a Maven test application to check that it was Heroku's fault instead of my program's.

`src/main/java/com/test/App.java`:

```
package com.test;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.IOException;
public class App{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        System.out.println(new Scanner(new ProcessBuilder(Arrays.asList("java", "A")).start().getInputStream()).nextLine());
    }
}
```

`A.java`:

```
public class A{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Test");
    }
}
```

`pom.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>test</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>

  <name>test</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
          <configuration>
            <archive>
              <manifest>
                <mainClass>com.test.App</mainClass>
              </manifest>
            </archive>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

After `javac A.java`, `mvn install`, and `java -jar target/test-1.0.jar`, it prints "Test" on my computer, but throws a `NoSuchElementException` in Heroku.

Full Stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1540)
    at com.test.App.main(App.java:7)
```

Does anyone know what's causing this and how to fix it?

Edit: Attatched [Github repo](https://github.com/Osrepnay/test) to hopefully make it clearer

Edit Edit: Oddly, if I put `A.java` in `src/main/java` and use the command from @Malax's answer, it works, but I still don't get why Heroku isn't seeing the java file outside of `src`. Maybe it's trimming them out to save space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue occurs because you're calling `nextLine` on `Scanner` without checking if there even is a line. You need to check with `hasNext` to ensure `nextLine` will not fail.

The underlying reason why you get no lines is that you're not specifying a classpath when invoking `java`. `java` will not be able to find your compiled `A` class without it and fail with something like

```
Error: Could not find or load main class A
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: A
```

on STDERR which you don't capture with `getInputStream`. You will be able to read the error message when you use `getErrorStream` instead (but then you won't get the STDOUT messages).

This has nothing to do with Heroku and I can only speculate why this is working for you locally. To provide `java` a classpath, you can use `-cp`:

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(Arrays.asList("java", "-cp", "target/classes", "A"));
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(processBuilder.start().getInputStream());
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
}
```

Comment: `A.java` is at the root directory of the Maven project. I've already tried `getErrorStream()` in Heroku and my computer, and in my computer it throws the exception because there are no errors, and in Heroku it also doesn't read anything.

Comment: I've attached a github repo to the question and see if it clears things up

Comment: Thx, this indirectly solved the problem by pointing me toward the direction of putting the files in the `src/main/java` directory... but I'd still like to know why it's not recognizing it in the root directory. Any pointers?